# error C2666: 'std::fpos<_Mbstatet>::operator +' : 2 overloads have similar conversions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I got the above error on the code snippet below, I fixed this error. But I'm unsure about the fix, could you please let me know if the fix is not good. Thanks for your time!

Code Snippet:

```
// get length
//long length = strlen( statement)+5; 
std::streamoff length = strlen(statement) + 5; // Fix for the error

// ckeck length and stream size against max buffer size
if( (m_sqlStream.tellp()+length)>=BATCH_WRITER_BUFFER_SIZE) //c2666
```

Output:

```
error C2666: 'std::fpos<_Mbstatet>::operator +' : 2 overloads have similar conversions
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\iosfwd(88): could be 'std::fpos<_Mbstatet> std::fpos<_Mbstatet>::operator +(std::streamoff) const'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\comutil.h(174): or       '_bstr_t operator +(const wchar_t *,const _bstr_t &)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\comutil.h(173): or       '_bstr_t operator +(const char *,const _bstr_t &)'
while trying to match the argument list '(std::fpos<_Mbstatet>, long)'
```

Comment: I guess msvc has messed up implicit conversion rules (To get to a _bstr_t: long -> _variant_t -> _bstr_t

Comment: I the m_sqlStream is a custom class, please post it

Comment: @DieterLücking I guess it's just a `std::ofstream`.

Comment: @DieterLücking Here's the definition: strstream m_sqlStream;

Answer (score 0):

I think it's right. The `std::streamsize` and `std::streamoff` are required to be typedefs of an integral type, and they can be converted to/from integral types.
The compiler complains because it can't determine which overload of operator + is appropriate since the parameters can be converted implicitly more than one way. For example:

```
void f(int, double);
void f(double, int);

int main() {
    f(3, 4);   // C2666! 3 or 4 can be converted to a int or a double, compiler can't resolve this ambiguity.
}
```

You can clarify it by casting one or more of the actual parameters explicitly:

```
if ((long)m_sqlStream.tellp() + length) >= BATCH_WRITER_BUFFER_SIZE)
```

or do just what you have done.
Note the compiler may warn you about possible loss of data while conversion from `std::streamoff` to `long`, it's because `std::streamoff` is a signed integral type defined by your C++ standard library implementation, and large enough to cater for the largest possible file sizes.

Comment: One has to wonder what the function that adds a string to a file position indicator does ...

Comment: add a string? I'm confused, `length` is not a string.

Comment: Oh, I didn't pay close enough attention to the compiler output. The other overload option is the free function `operator+` between two strings. It must be that `tellp()`'s result is implicitly convertible to `char *`, and `_bstr_t` also takes integral types in a non-explicit constructor.